# NAV 2013 R2 Performance on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, hardware, navision

The SQL Server is running on a well o:) configured server. The server configuration is given below.

1. OS - Windows Server 2012 R2
2. RAM - DDR3 24 GB ECC
3. RAID 10

The NAV SERVER is also installed on the same server. Almost 112 concurrent end-users are accessing the NAVISION database through different clients system.

I have noticed that at a particular time (5PM/6PM) the SQL as well as the NAV SERVER are consuming the whole (20GB+) RAM of the server everybody & makes the server unstable.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add more RAM? But seriously, you can set the max server memory for SQL Server to less than it currently is if you wanted. SQL will use as much RAM as it can. Beware that limiting this too much will have a negative impact on the performance of SQL.

Comment: Ok. more RAM will be added in near future. But what will be the max server memory for SQL Server in this circumstance ?

Comment: What is it now or what should it be?

Comment: Current Value is 2147483647 MB.

Comment: Well set it to a limit that leaves enough memory for the other things + the OS too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always happening in a particular time you should have to figure what is hammering it. 
SQL job? Something in NAV? Windows Task? Antivirus? Some user is running something which affecting it (copying thousands of files to network share for example)?

But yes - adding more RAM is always good.